# Peer to Peer replication ID number

Tags: sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I'm familiar with P2P replication conflicts which normally show along the lines of

```
conflict detected between peer 1 (incoming) and peer 2 (on disk).
```

The issue I'm seeing is that the conflicts are stating:

> ```
> conflict detected between peer 1 (incoming) and peer 1 (on disk) was detected 
> and resolved. The incoming update was skipped by peer 2.
> ```

This error is happening on peer 2.

#### Questions

- What I don't understand, and need some guidance, is why would peer `2` show me that the `on disk` is peer `1`?
- Is there any place I can look to see if maybe the ID of `1` was assigned to my peer `2` SQL server?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Interesting question. How many nodes do you haven in your peer-to-peer network (transactional replication) environment? Is that the actual error message or a redacted version? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.   We have two nodes at two sites (total of four node) with each site having a primary and a secondary.  That is the actual error wording, just the node number has been changed. The activity being tracked is between the two primary nodes.